# Что в Java означает строка package и что пишется до нее?

Tags: java

Когда пишешь код есть строчка package, что она означает и что пишеться до нее?

Comment: А вы читали документацию? Вам что-то в ней непонятно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пакет (package) представляют собой набор классов, объединённых по смыслу. Пакеты обычно вкладываются друг в друга, образуя собо иерархию, дающую понять, что зачем. На файловой системе такая иерархия выглядит в виде вложенных друг в друга директорий с исходниками. Так, исходники пакета a лежат в папке a, исходники пакета a.b — в папке a/b и так далее. Типичный путь к пакету выглядит примерно так:
org.apache.commons.collectons. Видите, сразу ясно зачем он нужен. Чтобы использовать какой-то класс в коде другого класса, вы должны импортировать его, написав до объявления класса строку
import путь.к.классу.ИмяКласса;
Кроме того, если вы используете классы одного пакета часто, вы можете импортировать весь пакет:
import путь.к.классу.*;
Это относится ко всем пакетам, кроме java.lang — он импортирован по умолчанию, именно из него были в прошлом примере взяты классы System и String. На самом деле они лежат в некоем jar'е, в каталоге java/lang.

Comment: если у меня работа с массивом к примеру, умножить все его элементы на пять, тут, я так понимаю, ничего импортировать не надо и перед package ничего не будет, я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: `package`, вроде, в любом случае - первая строка файла. После него идут импорты, потом определение класса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет, есть дефолтный пакетж, он объявляется без всяких записей.

Comment: @Vartlok, да, вы правы, надо было об этом упомянуть)

Comment: понял, спасибо.